# Are there furniture items that conflict with each other?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So basically, can I just buy anything that is available or do I have to select the most appropriate items for my style? It seems there are no conflicts from some quick testing. Though that would be less interesting it would also be much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only conflicts at workbenches are the choice of which wings you build; within each wing, you will be able to build every item.

The closest thing to a conflict inside each room, is in the trophy room; you can build every base, but then only have a limited number of bases to build the trophies on. Since they can't be un-built, you'll have to choose wisely, assuming you even build that room.